# Viewstate Issue with Dynamically Loaded Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, postback, viewstate

I am having issues with my dynamically loaded control's events.

Here is how I am loading the control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadSubPageEditTemplate();
}

protected void LoadSubPageEditTemplate()
{
        pnlPageTemplate.Controls.Clear();
        BaseOfferAdmin adminControl = (BaseOfferAdmin)this.LoadControl("~/Controls/SingleOfferAdmin.ascx");                        
        if (adminControl != null)
        {
            adminControl.ID = "Control_ID"
            pnlPageTemplate.Controls.Add(adminControl);
        }
    }
}
```

The LoadSubPageEditTemplate() is also fired from a button event on the page, since I have to update it after the button event has executed.

The control loads perfectly, I have tested it with a basic button and the postback fires as expected. However, I am getting weird results with CheckBoxes.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbOptionalAction" Text="CheckBox" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbOptionalAction_CheckChanged" />
```

The CheckedChanged event only fires when the Checkbox is checked, which I guess means there is some issue with my control viewstate. If I have multiple checkboxes on the page, and one creates a postback, the checkchanged event is fired for each checkbox that is checked.

Thanks for anyone taking some time out to help me out!

Ignus

Comment: did you tried to call LoadSubPageEditTemplate(); in Page_Init event instead of Page_Load? Page_Init would be considered best place to generate the dynamic controls. You may find this related article helpful: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Please load control only when page is not postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
        {        
             LoadSubPageEditTemplate();
        }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, when the postback from the user control fires, it needs to be added again from the page. If I only add it on !PostBack, after the postback, the control is gone.